# For-loop to count differences in lines with python

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I have a file filled with lines like this (this is just a small bit of the file):

9 Hyphomicrobium        facile  Hyphomicrobiaceae
9 Hyphomicrobium        facile  Hyphomicrobiaceae
7 Mycobacterium kansasii        Mycobacteriaceae
7 Mycobacterium gastri  Mycobacteriaceae
10 Streptomyces olivaceiscleroticus     Streptomycetaceae
10 Streptomyces niger   Streptomycetaceae
1 Streptomyces  geysiriensis    Streptomycetaceae
1 Streptomyces  minutiscleroticus       Streptomycetaceae
0 Brucella      neotomae        Brucellaceae
0 Brucella      melitensis      Brucellaceae
2 Mycobacterium phocaicum       Mycobacteriaceae

The number refers to a cluster, and then it goes 'Genus' 'Species' 'Family'.
What I want to do is write a program that will look through each line and report back to me: a list of the different genera in each cluster, and how many of each of those genera are in the cluster. So I'm interested in cluster number and the first 'word' in each line.

My trouble is that I'm not sure how to get this information. I think I need to use a for-loop, starting at lines that begin with '0.'The output would be a file that looks something like:

Cluster 0: Brucella(2) # Lists cluster, followed by genera in cluster with number, something like that.
Cluster 1: Streptomyces(2)
Cluster 2: Brucella(1)
etc.

Eventually I want to do the same kind of count with the Families in each cluster, and then Genera and Species together. Any thoughts on how to start would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this would be a fun little toy project, so I wrote a little hack to read in an input file like yours from stdin, count and format the output recursively and spit out output that looks a little like yours, but with a nested format, like so:

```
Cluster 0:
    Brucella(2)
        melitensis(1)
            Brucellaceae(1)
        neotomae(1)
            Brucellaceae(1)
    Streptomyces(1)
        neotomae(1)
            Brucellaceae(1)
Cluster 1:
    Streptomyces(2)
        geysiriensis(1)
            Streptomycetaceae(1)
        minutiscleroticus(1)
            Streptomycetaceae(1)
Cluster 2:
    Mycobacterium(1)
        phocaicum(1)
            Mycobacteriaceae(1)
Cluster 7:
    Mycobacterium(2)
        gastri(1)
            Mycobacteriaceae(1)
        kansasii(1)
            Mycobacteriaceae(1)
Cluster 9:
    Hyphomicrobium(2)
        facile(2)
            Hyphomicrobiaceae(2)
Cluster 10:
    Streptomyces(2)
        niger(1)
            Streptomycetaceae(1)
        olivaceiscleroticus(1)
            Streptomycetaceae(1)
```

I also added some junk data to my table so that I could see an extra entry in Cluster 0, separated from the other two...  The idea here is that you should be able to see a top level "Cluster" entry and then nested, indented entries for genus, species, family...  it shouldn't be hard to extend for deeper trees, either, I hope.

```
# Sys for stdio stuff
import sys
# re for the re.split -- this can go if you find another way to parse your data
import re


# A global (shame on me) for storing the data we're going to parse from stdin
data = []

# read lines from standard input until it's empty (end-of-file)
for line in sys.stdin:
    # Split lines on spaces (gobbling multiple spaces for robustness)
    # and trim whitespace off the beginning and end of input (strip)
    entry = re.split("\s+", line.strip())

    # Throw the array into my global data array, it'll look like this:
    # [ "0", "Brucella", "melitensis", "Brucellaceae" ]
    # A lot of this code assumes that the first field is an integer, what
    # you call "cluster" in your problem description
    data.append(entry)

# Sort, first key is expected to be an integer, and we want a numerical
# sort rather than a string sort, so convert to int, then sort by
# each subsequent column. The lamba is a function that returns a tuple
# of keys we care about for each item
data.sort(key=lambda item: (int(item[0]), item[1], item[2], item[3]))


# Our recursive function -- we're basically going to treat "data" as a tree,
# even though it's not.
# parameters:
#    start - an integer telling us what line to begin working from so we needn't
#            walk the whole tree each time to figure out where we are.
#    super - An array that captures where we are in the search. This array
#            will have more elements in it as we deepen our traversal of the "tree"
#            Initially, it will be []
#            In the next ply of the tree, it will be [ '0' ]
#            Then something like [ '0', 'Brucella' ] and so on.
#    data -  The global data structure -- this never mutates after the sort above,
#            I could have just used the global directly
def groupedReport(start, super, data):
    # Figure out what ply we're on in our depth-first traversal of the tree
    depth =  len(super)
    # Count entries in the super class, starting from "start" index in the array:
    count = 0

    # For the few records in the data file that match our "super" exactly, we count
    # occurrences.
    if depth != 0:
        for i in range(start, len(data)):
            if (data[i][0:depth] == data[start][0:depth]):
                count = count + 1
            else:
                break; # We can stop counting as soon as a match fails,
                   # because of the way our input data is sorted
    else:
        count = len(data)


    # At depth == 1, we're reporting about clusters -- this is the only piece of
    # the algorithm that's not truly abstract, and it's only for presentation
    if (depth == 1):
        sys.stdout.write("Cluster " + super[0] + ":\n")
    elif (depth > 0):
        # Every other depth: indent with 4 spaces for every ply of depth, then
        # output the unique field we just counted, and its count
        sys.stdout.write((' ' * ((depth - 1) * 4)) +
                         data[start][depth - 1] + '(' + str(count) + ')\n')

    # Recursion: we're going to figure out a new depth and a new "super"
    # and then call ourselves again. We break out on depth == 4 because
    # of one other assumption (I lied before about the abstract thing) I'm
    # making about our input data here. This could
    # be made more robust/flexible without a lot of work
    subsuper = None
    substart = start
    for i in range(start, start + count):
        record = data[i]  # The original record from our data
        newdepth = depth + 1
        if (newdepth > 4): break;

        # array splice creates a new copy
        newsuper = record[0:newdepth]
        if newsuper != subsuper:
            # Recursion here!
            groupedReport(substart, newsuper, data)
            # Track our new "subsuper" for subsequent comparisons
            # as we loop through matches
            subsuper = newsuper

        # Track position in the data for next recursion, so we can start on
        # the right line
        substart = substart + 1

# First call to groupedReport starts the recursion
groupedReport(0, [], data)
```

If you make my Python code into a file like "classifier.py", then you can run your input.txt file (or whatever you call it) through it like so:

```
cat input.txt | python classifier.py
```

Most of the magic of the recursion, if you care, is implemented using slices of arrays and leans heavily on the ability to compare array slices, as well as the fact that I can order the input data meaningfully with my sort routine. You may want to convert your input data to all-lowercase, if it is possible that case inconsistencies could yield mismatches.

Comment: Just a quick question, when I run this, this appears at the top: Brucellaceae(28)
(why is it putting Brucellaceae(28) at the top?)

Comment: I may have a bug; if you wanna give me your real input, I'll sort it out.

Comment: The real input is a large file that I have, is that possible to share? Would you be willing to explain how this code works, just briefly? Just because it's perfect for what I'm doing and I want to make sure I understand what's happening in it so I can use it in different ways in the future! Thanks again for this! :D

Comment: I'm asking so I can understand how to alter the code so that it would only look at genus, or only at family.

Comment: Okay, @Jen, I've added loads of comments, please feel free to ask questions. My guess is your input file does not have a "cluster" integer on that first line, so it's falling afoul of my assumptions, as described in the new comments. Let me know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32588/discussion-between-crowder-and-jen)

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do.

1. create an empty dict `{}` to store your result, lets call it 'result'
2. Loop over the data line by line.
3. Split the line on space to get 4 elements as per your structure, `cluster,genus,species,family`
4. Increment counts of genus inside each cluster key when they are found in the current loop, they have to be set to 1 for the first occurence though.

`result = { '0': { 'Brucella': 2} ,'1':{'Streptomyces':2}..... }`

Code:

```
my_data = """9 Hyphomicrobium facile Hyphomicrobiaceae                                                   
9 Hyphomicrobium facile Hyphomicrobiaceae                                                                
7 Mycobacterium kansasii Mycobacteriaceae                                                                
7 Mycobacterium gastri Mycobacteriaceae                                                                  
10 Streptomyces olivaceiscleroticus Streptomycetaceae                                                    
10 Streptomyces niger Streptomycetaceae                                                                  
1 Streptomyces geysiriensis Streptomycetaceae                                                            
1 Streptomyces minutiscleroticus Streptomycetaceae                                                       
0 Brucella neotomae Brucellaceae                                                                         
0 Brucella melitensis Brucellaceae                                                                       
2 Mycobacterium phocaicum Mycobacteriaceae"""

result = {}
for line in my_data.split("\n"):
    cluster,genus,species,family = line.split(" ")
    result.setdefault(cluster,{}).setdefault(genus,0)
    result[cluster][genus] += 1

print(result)


{'10': {'Streptomyces': 2}, '1': {'Streptomyces': 2}, '0': {'Brucella': 2}, '2': {'Mycobacterium': 1}, '7': {'Mycobacterium': 2}, '9': {'Hyphomicrobium': 2}}
```

Comment: thanks for answering! Would it destroy the dictionary to split each line into the four elements? (i'm probably asking a dumb question)

Comment: Thanks! I keep getting this error though, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sort.py", line 7, in <module>
    for line in result.split("\n"):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'